# Changing RichEditBox Selection Text throws AccessViolationException

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, richeditbox

I am trying to develop a feature where a user can select from a list of hastags and FriendList and add them to RichEditBox as he types using Auto suggestions, kinda like auto complete. Here is the code that does this.

```
private void MentionSuggestionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(_postText[i]) || _postText[i] == '_')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (_postText[i] == '@' || _postText[i] == '#')
                {
                    flag = true;
                    index = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition = index;

                //AccessViolationException here
                PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, (e.AddedItems[0] as MentionUserModel).screenName + " "); 
                PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting AccessViolation randomly when I change the selection text of richeditbox. Its random but its frequent enough that I can replicate it everytime in few tried only. I can even catch this Exception. What should I do?

Something similar to my question on msdn [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a15d2b13-6a81-400c-9d28-57a791404cc3/how-to-set-multiple-links-in-richeditbox-without-accessviolationexception?forum=wpdevelop) according to which its a known issue. But Rudy huyn's 6tag does this flawlessly. how?

I tried to change RichEditBox with TextBox and it still happens on that control also.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing all the text outside RichEditBox and then adding it back. This is just a workaround though. I wish win rt was more stable and feature rich as silverlight.

```
private void MentionSuggestionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int endpos = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition;
        int startpos = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition;
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(_postText[i]) || _postText[i] == '_')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (_postText[i] == '@' || _postText[i] == '#')
                {
                    flag = true;
                    index = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                //PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition = index;
                //PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition = endpos;
                String post="";
                PostRichEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out post);
                string result = post.Substring(0, index);
                result = result + (e.AddedItems[0] as MentionUserModel).screenName + " ";
                result = result + post.Substring(endpos, (post.Length - 1) - endpos);

                int size = endpos - index;
                size = ((e.AddedItems[0] as MentionUserModel).screenName + " ").Length - size;

                PostRichEditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, result);
                //PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, (e.AddedItems[0] as MentionUserModel).screenName + " ");
                PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.StartPosition = PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition = size + endpos;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try again by using the following syntax:

```
PostRichEditBox.Document.Selection.FormattedText.SetText(…);
```

This should permanently solve your problem without using workarounds.
My best wishes!